# How to build Python Lambda for Alexa skill with sequence of statements?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am building Alexa skill for my application. When your ask's 'what is my account status?' this intent return sequence of statements related to user's account. API gives following response

```
response = [{
..
text: 'Total orders are 41, Delivered 28'
..
},
{
..
text: 'Today orders are 12, Delivered 2'
..
},
{}]
```

How to build response sequence based on API response?

With this intent, I get the response from API with set statements Alexa should prompt each statement one by one. If the user said 'next' in between any of the statement while Alexa prompting then it goes to next statement in the response array.

Comment: could you elaborate what do you want to mean with "when the user said 'next' in between of current statement to goes to next statement to should prompt"? 

If you want to keep a session between requests, I suggest taking a look at the alexa tutorial https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-skills-kit/big-nerd-ranch/alexa-voice-user-interfaces-and-sessions

Comment: With this intent, I get the response from API with set statements Alexa should prompt each statement one by one. If user said next in between any of the statement to goes to next statement in the response array.

Answer (score 1):

First when user says `"what is my account status?`" your intent will be called and you will get response in a list where in the first call you will display 0th item.

API Result:

```
response = [{
..
text: 'Total orders are 41, Delivered 28'
..
},
{
..
text: 'Today orders are 12, Delivered 2'
..
},
{}]
```

You need to store information in Session attributes, like intent name, index which you displayed (0 in case of first call) etc.
Now you need to setup one more intent which will be triggered on keywords like `next`. In the code you will check values of session attributes and make your response according to the values. For example you would want to check previous intent name, previous index. If all is fine you will modify the session attributes and respond to user.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Python, I would suggest to take a look at [Flask-ask](https://alexatutorial.com/flask-ask/), which provides you with two main responses type: statement and question.

As [sid8491](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3196845/sid8491) mentioned, you will need to store info in sessions to keep track of which response (from json) needs to be returned. You can use [redis](https://redis.io/download) for this purpose, using [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis) python library.

Assuming the json response is stored in db (or somewhere), and can be accessed in a list, let's say your interaction model looks something like this:

```
{
    "languageModel": {
        "intents": [
            {
                "name": "NextIntent",
                "samples": ["next", "tell me more"]
            },
            {
                "name": "StopIntent",
                "samples": ["stop"]
            },
            {
                "name": "StatusIntent",
                "samples": ["what is my account status"]
            }
        ],
        "invocationName": "orders"
    }
}
```

You can use following steps (using redis and flask-ask for this example):

1. on 'StatusIntent', store session and return first response:

   ```
   redis.set("session_key", 0)
   return statement(response[0]) # assuming responses are stored in a list
   ```
2. on 'NextIntent', get value stored in session, if present return next response

   ```
   value = redis.get("session_key")
   if not value:  # session is expired
       return statement("I don't understand")
   redis.set("session_key", int(value)+1)
   return statement(response[int(value)+1])
   ```
3. on 'StopIntent', remove "session_key" from redis

   ```
   redis.delete("session_key")
   return statement("Ok. I am here if you need me.")
   ```

It's not the actual code but simply intended to give you an idea. Hope it helps.

:)